# How can I install a module in python 3.7 in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, kinect, sudo

So, I am new to ubuntu and currently I am working with a kinect and consequently I found the freenect module to work on.

But the problem is that I am having a hard time on installing this package on python, more specifically python 3.7, because the command pip (or pip3) can not find the freenect module.

So, the solution is to go with cloning the freenect repository on github and then after creating directories and bla bla bla you make sudo install.

But, for the last step, which is going to the folder "/libfreenect/wrappers/python" and running:

`sudo python setup.py install`

The output tells me that I installed in python 2.7 which is not the python version I am currently working with.
So then after I tried with:

`sudo python3 setup.py install`

But it was installed in python 3.6 which is also not the one I am using, like the title says, I am using python 3.7.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Maybe it's better if you navigate to the proper python installetion (I mean `cd` to it) and directly call the pytho nfile and execute your `sudo your_pythonfile setup.py install` . This is just **a** solution. You should actually set your python in the system path

Comment: you should use pyenv: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you had installed pip3 as:

```
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3
```

then check it through as:

```
pip3 --version
```

and install from https://pypi.org if available

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! Yeah I done all of that, the problem is that freenect is not available in pypi.org, but freenect2 is, so I will just adjust my work to work with this new one. Thank you!